# What type of chorizo is this?

Tags: sausages, raw-meat, spanish-cuisine

I have been given a gourmet hamper which includes a chorizo sausage.  There are no instructions on the packet to say what it is.  I have had cooking chorizo before and know what it looks like.  This chorizo is about 8 inches long, has string at both ends and is quite soft.  I don't want to give anyone a stomach upset.  To cook or not to cook.

Regards Carol.

Comment: Can you add a picture?  Do you have a country of origin?

Comment: Is the skin wrinkled or smooth?

Comment: The skin is smooth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of the largest clues to help you

1. If it's Spanish, it's probably OK 'raw', if it's Mexican, probably not.
2. If it's soft & squashy, it needs cooking, if it's firm & wrinkled it's OK as it is.

Left is cured & ready to eat, right must be cooked first.

[image]

<sup>I'm ignoring the fact that for this photo someone has cross-contaminated, making the properly smoked one no longer safe</sup>

One additional tip I learned from my mother-in law, who lives in Spain - even though completely safe 'raw', if the skin comes off easily in one piece, it's better raw; if it tears off in bits, cook it anyway in red wine. It's not as good.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, very informative  .I live in Spain and It says on the box that the chorizo was made in Salamanca-España so I guess It's the real thing also my chorizo looks like the one on the left in your picture.  Thanks for taking the trouble to answer my question, it's really clarified my question.